# Automated IIS backups at the application level?

Tags: backup, iis-7, iis

I'm exploring automated backups when deploying to IIS 7 using webdeploy.  I've upgraded to webdeploy v3 after ensuring that Management Service is installed and running under my web server role, all of which is required for automated backups.

Using the configuration editor within IIS manager, I've enabled and "turned on" the backup feature at the SERVER level.  This functions as expected.  Any deployment of a site or component of a site using webdeploy creates a full backup of that site.

What I've been unable to do is to create application-level backups.  My site, the Default Web Site, is composed of multiple applications(wcf webservices) each residing in their own virtual directory.  Each of my applications is deployed separately, so I'd like each of them to have their own backup, instead of backing up the whole site each time an application is deployed.

I have modified the configuration (web.config) of one of the applications to enable and turn-on backups.  A deployment of the application using webdeploy does not trigger a backup.  I've tried various combinations of settings within the hierarchy(server enabled/turned off, site enabled/turned off, application enabled/turned on.....server enabled/turned off, site enabled/turned on, application enabled/turned on...etc), and the only setting that has an effect is to set the server enabled/turned on, which creates a site-level backup.

Has anyone had success performing automated backups at a more granular level than the entire site?  If so what's the magic combination of backup settings at the server/site/application-level hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `Backup-WDAPP` for backing up an application. More info [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets).

```
Backup-WDApp "Default web site/app"
```